# How can I keep a local folder that is also syncing with iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

I have a local folder where I keep some projects, I want it to be syncing in an iCloud folder but still have it as a local folder.

I've tried symlinks but the problem is that the folder will be deleted from my local machine and then will only exists on the iCloud folder.

Is there any way to have a copy of that folder on ICloud and syncing?

Answer (score 1):

No - you would want to locate the files in an iCloud folder. It’s pretty easy to keep folders downloaded, though. Using symbolic links won’t get you where you want to be - so I would clean them up and then re-enable desktop and documents storage.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985

Have you run into issues with keeping files around when the network is disconnected? Documents is still on your mac, so the files should sync to the cloud and remain there as long as you don’t enable “optimize space” in the settings.